# CSS Div Of Width Auto Filling Entire Parent Div

Tags: css, html, width

This is my code:

```
.divUserRepCont
{
    position: absolute;

    top: 0;
    left: 105px;

    width: 195px;
    height: 25px;   
}

.divUserContCon
{
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;

    background-color: red;
}

.divUserCon
{
    width: 50px;
    height: 20px;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="divUserRepCont">
    <div class="divUserContCon">
        <div class="divUserCon">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am expecting a red bar of width 50px, but instead the auto width "divUserContCon" is filling up the entire 195px of it's parent div. Why is this?

**EDIT:**

The purpose of divUserContCon having an auto width is because of this:

divUserCon's size will be changing dynamically, and it will have a background colour itself.

divUserContCon, will be the container for divUserCon, which itself will have a background colour AND padding.

So if divUserCon is 50px wide, with a green background, divUserContCon will be 50px wide (auto) + some padding and it's background colour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
width:50px;
```

Needs to be put in divUserContCon. You can't rely on auto to only take up the width of any child divs.

Comment: divUserCon's size will be changing dynamically. It could be 80px, 90px etc... so I cannot set the width or divUserContCon to anything other than auto.

Comment: Ok, so set the background-colour of .divuserCon to be red instead then? We might need more context about what you're trying to do :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<style type="text/css">
.divUserRepCont {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 105px;
  width: 195px;
  height: 25px;   
}
.divUserContCon {
    width: auto;
    height: 25px;
}
.divUserCon {
    width: 50px;
    height: 25px;
    background-color: red;
}
</style>
```

If you want your `.divUserCon` in the `center` then just add `margin: 0 auto;` in the css.

Comment: See main post for a revision, I cannot use that method.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it:

```
.divUserRepCont
{
    position: absolute;

    top: 0;
    left: 105px;

    width: 195px;
    height: 25px;   

    background-color: orange;
}

.divUserContCon
{
    display: inline-block;

    height: 100%;

    padding-right: 20px;

    background-color: yellow;
}

.divUserCon
{
    display: inline-block;
    height: 20px;

    border-top: 5px solid rgb(62, 62, 62);

    background-color: red;
}
```

**I replaced the width: auto with display: inline-block;**